# Filling a big rectangle with a variable quantity of little rectangles

Tags: c#, wpf, fill, rectangles

I'm trying to fill a rectangle with a variable quantity of little rectangles but adjusting the distance between them depending on the number of units (more units->the lesser the distance between).

I'm a newbie programming WPF in C# and i don´t know how to advance from this point.

How can I do it?

The code so far:

```
int units = 20;
int width = 10;
int height = 20;
int top = 200;
int left = 200;
int rectangleWidth = 300;
int rectangleHeight = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < units; i++)
{
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle()
    {
        Width = width,
        Height = height,
        Fill = Brushes.Black,
        Stroke = Brushes.White,
        StrokeThickness = 1,
        RadiusX = 3,
        RadiusY = 3,
    };

    cuadernodibujo.Children.Add(rec);
    Canvas.SetTop(rec, top);
    Canvas.SetLeft(rec, left + (i*50));
}
```

I have updated the code, but doesn´t work.
I don´t know what am i doing wrong.
The piece of code so far:

```
        int rectangleWidth = 500;
        int rectangleHeight = 100;
        int units = 60;
        int unitsX = 10;
        int unitsY = 6;
        var childWidht = (rectangleWidth - 2*Left) / unitsX;
        var childHeigth = (rectangleHeight - 2*Top ) / unitsY;
        int width = 10;
        int height = 20;
        double top = 100;
        double left = 100;

        for (int i = 0; i < units; i++)
        {
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle()
            {
                Width = width,
                Height = height,
                Fill = Brushes.Black,
                Stroke = Brushes.White,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                RadiusX = 3,
                RadiusY = 3,
            };

            cuadernodibujo.Children.Add(rec);
            for (int j = 0; j < unitsY; j++) 
            {
                Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle()
                {
                    Width = width,
                    Height = height,
                    Fill = Brushes.Black,
                    Stroke = Brushes.White,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    RadiusX = 3,
                    RadiusY = 3,
                };


                cuadernodibujo.Children.Add(rec2);
                Canvas.SetTop(rec, top + (j * childHeigth)); 

                for (int k = 0; k < unitsX; k++) 
                {
                    Rectangle rec3 = new Rectangle()
                    {
                        Width = width,
                        Height = height,
                        Fill = Brushes.Black,
                        Stroke = Brushes.White,
                        StrokeThickness = 1,
                        RadiusX = 3,
                        RadiusY = 3,
                    };
                    cuadernodibujo.Children.Add(rec3);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(rec, left + (k * childWidht)); 

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your problem is you have mulitple `add`s, in multiple loops. You should only need one `add` in the inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to spread the **little rectangles** uniformly over the width of the **parent rectangle**.

This is less a programming problem, then a maths problem.

Given the  **parent rectangle's** width `parentWidht` and the number of **child rectangles** `units` each child rectangle has a width of:

```
var childWidht = parentWidht / units;
```

If you want to add a left and right margin (given your `left` variable), you need to subtract the margin from `parentWidht`.

```
var childWidht = (parentWidht - 2 * left) / units; // 2 times left, to add the margin on both sides.
```

This gives you the width of each child, you now only have to move each **child rectangle** according to the previously calculated `childWidht`.

```
...
var childWidht = (parentWidht - 2 * left) / units; 
for (int i = 0; i < units; i++)
{
    ...
    Canvas.SetLeft(rec, left + (i*childWidht));
}
```

### Update to question in the comments

> With that I can fill a single line, but how can I fill the rest of the lines (to fill the parent height as well)?

We can apply the same logic as for the horizontal filling.

1. First calculate the **child rectangles** height (`parentHeight - 2 * top)`
2. Then wrap the horizontal rectangles into a loop and move each line according to the calculated height.

Here the listing with horizontal and vertical filling.

```
...
var childWidht = (parentWidht - 2 * left) / unitsX; 
var childHeigth = (parentHeigth - 2 * top) / unitsY; 

for (int j = 0; j < unitsY; i++) // first loop for vertical filling
{
    for (int i = 0; i < unitsX; i++) // second loop for horizontal
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle { ... } ;
        Canvas.Children.Add(rect); // Only add once in the inner loop.
        Canvas.SetTop(rec, top + (j * childHeigth)); // here we use j, the vertical index
        Canvas.SetLeft(rec, left + (i*childWidht)); // here we use i, the horizontal index
    }
}
```

Comment: With that i can fill a single line, but how can i fill the rest of the lines  (to fill the parentHeight aswell)?

Comment: @Fidel I have updated the answer to include horizontal and vertical filling.

Comment: i have tested your code, but throws me an error at cuadernodibujo.Children.Add(rec); (Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget)

Comment: Can you post the full piece of code to check if i´m doing something wrong?

Comment: The error states that you have tried to add the same item twice. As in your original posting you have to create a new item for every loop.

Comment: I don't have a full piece of code, the examples above are pseudo code based on your listing

Comment: I have updated the question with the current code. It is drawing only 2 rectangles.

Comment: That seems to solve the problem, now i have to adjust things a bit. Thx